# Cannot represent due to `character_code'

Tags: prolog

Мой код:

```
parent(pamela, bob).
parent(tom, bob).
parent(tom, liz).
parent(bob, ann).
parent(bob, patricia).
parent(patricia, jim).

ancestor(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y); ancestor(X, Z), parent(Z, Y).

query2 :- ancestor(bob, patricia).
```

На запрос:

```
query2.
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
Actions:

; (n, r, space, TAB): redo    t:          trace & redo
b:                    break   c (a, RET): exit
w:                    write   p           print
h (?):                help


ERROR: char_code/2: Cannot represent due to `character_code'
true Action?
```

Запускал в онлайн трансляторе ([ссылка](https://rextester.com/l/prolog_online_compiler)).

Что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: Да вроде бы все правильно, даже ответ правильный выдала система. Я запросил предикат `parent(X, Y)`, он выдает правильные ответы, но эта ошибка остается, запустил на swi, все работает таких ошибок нет. Такое чувство, что это что-то с интерпретатором происходит в тот момент, когда ему нужно запросить у пользователя дополнительные действия

Comment: Ясно, буду тогда на swi переходить, онлайн редакторы походу годятся лишь как временная мера...